# Out of Process COM Server with simultaneous 32 and 64 bit clients

Tags: c++, com

I have a 64bit out of process COM Server running on a 64bit machine.  I registered my 64bit Proxy/Stub DLL using regsvr32.exe in my `C:\Windows\System32` folder and can run my 64bit clients.  I have also registered my 32bit Proxy/Stub in the `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` folder and I can run my 32bit clients.  I can also run multiple 32bit clients at the same time, and multiple 64bit clients at the same time.  However, if I try to run a 32bit client and then a 64bit client, the second client attempts to create a new Server.exe process (same thing happens if I start with the 64bit client).  Shouldn't they all just use the same Server instance?

Here is my Server `CoCreateInstanceEx` Call:

```
HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstanceEx(CLSID_COMServerObject, NULL, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER | CLSCTX_ACTIVATE_64_BIT_SERVER, NULL, 1, &qi);
```

Both my Client `CoCreateInstanceEx` Calls look like this:

```
hr = CoCreateInstanceEx(clsid, NULL, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER | CLSCTX_ACTIVATE_64_BIT_SERVER, NULL, 1, &qi);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You never mentioned what the server does, it is important.  The REGCLS it passes to CoRegisterClassObject() matters a great deal.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry... I'm using ATL which is calling:  hr = pT->RegisterClassObjects(CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER,   REGCLS_MULTIPLEUSE | REGCLS_SUSPENDED);

Comment: The server is connecting to an Input device and sending updates to all clients.

Comment: Well this was not a bug I had with COM.  The 64 bit client was running as administrator and the 32 bit clients were not.  Forcing the 32 bit clients to also run as administrator solved the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 64 bit client was running as administrator and the 32 bit clients were not. Forcing the 32 bit clients to also run as administrator solved the issue